# BigQuery Data Transfer Service: frequency limit exceeded

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a Data Transfer from AWS S3 to BigQuery with an `every 12 hours` Repeats Custom Schedule but get the following error:

> Frequency limit exceeded. The required min_schedule_interval is [24h], the actual delay between [2021-03-15T14:45:00-07:00] and [2021-03-16T02:45:00-07:00] is [12h].

Setting the Custom Schedule to every 24 hours or more works fine, but any less produces this error.

According to the documentation for schedule options, ["the minimum interval is 15 minutes"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer).

Has anyone encountered this before or know how to resolve?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this @KEllis?

Comment: The work around I used was to have two seperate transfers 12 hours apart dumping data into the same time partitioned BigQuery table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and checked the documentation.

"the minimum interval is 15 minutes". seems to be the case for Cloud Storage.
In the case of AWS S3 integration, the minimum interval is 24 hours.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer#limitations

> The minimum interval time between recurring transfers is 24 hours. The default interval for a recurring transfer is 24 hours.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29811150)